# How to implement facebook login with strapi in ionic

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, strapi

I am wondering how to implement facebook login with strapi in ionic.

My question is: I have a button that will go trough http://localhost:1337/connect/facebook and it should be opening the facebook app on my phone. Once I log in how do go back automatically on the app with the users information? I have seen that it stores on the db but I am missing something on how to go back to application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Once the user presses the login button, your app will redirect him to `connect/facebook`.
Which will open Facebook for login in and after facebook will respond with `code` in URL to the URL that you set in Strapi provider configurations.

So you should handle the response in your frontend, take that `code` and send it to `http://localhost:1337/auth/:provider` URL of the backend, which will respond to you with user data.

Hope it'll work fine for you.

Comment: I will try, but in what way i would pass data? I want to use  ionic facebook 4 .... i will get the jwt, how I need to call backend to register user?

Comment: Strapi is doing registration by itself, as soon as User loges in by it's logic. This means when you implement process explained and user logs in your app, it will appear as registered user in you DB.